# Data attr in second td is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, attributes

Content comes from DB. I go `foreach` on array and insert rows into table. This is the structure of 1 row:

```
<tr>
    <td data-name = '<?php echo $name ?>'><?php echo $name ?></td>
    <td data-email = '<?php echo $email ?>'><?php echo $email ?></td>
    <td><form method='post'><button class='delete' name='delete' ...>Remove</button></form></td>
<tr>
```

I am trying to get the content of each data attribute in a row:

```
 $('.delete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let name = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td').data('name');
        let email = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td').data('email'); // <--- undefined  
        if (confirm(name + ' ' + email + ' delete?')) {
          ...code goes futher...
```

The question is:  I get name value, but email is undefined. What is wrong?
I also see the value of email variable in the table and in data attr in dev Console

Comment: Could it be that your second `.find('td')` targets the first `<td>` tag (i.e., the one with the `name` instead of the `email` attribute?)

Comment: ahhhh, yeap, it always asks the first td for the email data attr and finds none--- that is why undefined.

I though that its gonna search for td with data particulary "email"
Is there a simple way to get the second td with email data?

Comment: nevermind, got it already :)